# Taking different Table of Elements with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have this loop structure several times. 
Table 1

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>titulo</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table 2

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Texto</th>
            <th>Texto</th>
            <th>Texto</th>
            <th>Texto</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This pattern is repeated several times.
How do I switch them to an array and a list for me to get the values ​​of each ?

Answer (score 0):

Short Demo using a Console App:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load("Demo.html");
        var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")
            .Select(table => new //create anonymous type
                             {
                                 Table = table,
                                 HeaderNodes = table.SelectNodes("./tbody/tr/th").ToList() //the th subnodes
                             });
        foreach (var table in result)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode headerNode in table.HeaderNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( headerNode.InnerText);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
titulo
--------------------------
Texto
Texto
Texto
Texto
--------------------------
```

Comment: Alternative HeaderNodes = table.SelectNodes(".//th").ToList()

Comment: If you need an Array of tables just call .ToArray() after the Select

Comment: Or create your own type and do .Select(table => new Yourtype(){...}).ToArray();